# Magento2 - huge bulk products to upload in Magento

Tags: magento2

We are using **Retail Pro 9** as `POS` for our chains stores, we have around **7000** products we can export it from retail pro, what is the easiest  way to import all products in `Magento 2`.

Hope to have answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the easiest way to **import** the products it's through [Magento's import](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import.html) functionality. You will need however to export the data into a CSV format file and import it in Magento. For the **export**, I suggest you do an export of some dummy data in Magento via the [export feature](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-export.html) so that you see the columns and format needed for the import. Then you can export your products into that format and import it in Magento.
2. You could also use [Magento's rest API endpoint](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/productssku) to add the products by calling the **API** from your current system.

Whichever the approach, *-probably you already know this, but I will have a go with it-* I suggest you first check the Magento internal structure in terms of categories, attribute sets and stock management (specially concerning Multi Source Inventory).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I worked on integrating Retail Pro with Magento. Integration increase the accuracy and help

i) synchronize Item Catalog automatically on scheduled time.
ii) Synchronize Stock On Hand real time to Magento.
iii) Synchronize sales made in Magento to Retail Pro Version 9.

And many other omnichannel functionality can be added.